# How to import xml to jackrabbit?

Tags: xml, import, jackrabbit

I'm using `jackrabbit` `2.12` as a webapp deployed to `tomcat`. I created backup `xml` with

```
session.exportSystemView(..)
```

method. When I try to import this backup

```
InputStream xmlInputStream=new FileInputStream("d://sk.xml");
jcrSession.importXML("/",xmlInputStream,ImportUUIDBehavior.IMPORT_UUID_COLLISION_REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

this exception occured :

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:120)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:51)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.ExceptionConverter.generate(ExceptionConverter.java:45)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.RepositoryServiceImpl.isGranted(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:882)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.WorkspaceManager.canRead(WorkspaceManager.java:695)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.state.ItemStateValidator.checkIsWritable(ItemStateValidator.java:199)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.xml.SessionImporter.<init>(SessionImporter.java:130)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.SessionImpl.getImportContentHandler(SessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.SessionImpl.importXML(SessionImpl.java:390)
...
Caused by: org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.DavException: Internal Server Error
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.DavMethodBase.getResponseException(DavMethodBase.java:165)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.webdav.client.methods.DavMethodBase.checkSuccess(DavMethodBase.java:174)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.spi2dav.RepositoryServiceImpl.isGranted(RepositoryServiceImpl.java:854)
    ... 81 more
```

and tomcat catalina log:

```
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DavLocatorFactoryImpl.java:64 Unexpected format of resource path.
```

I found an [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-3763?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=15020993) about this problem but no suitable solution. How can I import this xml?
(Current files on the repository are insignificant, they can be deleted to import this `xml`.)

Comment: Could you please retry with a recent Jackrabbit version? See <http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/downloads.html#v2.18>

Comment: We don't want to update jackrabbit, we tested our application with this version. Are you sure that this issue fixed on new versions?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. It might be issue <https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-4120>. You sure have a test system, right? In which case testing a newer version should be very simple...

Comment: Tried with latest release (`2.16.3`), same error.

Comment: 2.16.3 doesn't have the fix for the issue. You need 2.16.4 or 2.18.0.

Comment: Tried with `2.18.0` too, same error.

Comment: OK, so please open a ticket at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/JCR/summary and supply as much information as you can, including detailed instructions how to reproduce, and log files (both client side and server side).